# JavaScriptResult writing the content on Response Stream itself

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am absolute new to MVC but have worked on ASP.NET. I was doing unit testing and functionality testing of one module and found some weird behavior (it's an old code base).

There is a non-controller class which inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute` and has method which gets invokes for every action method execution, I believe. This has call to a controller action method using `Response.Redirect()` like

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/FAQ/GetContent/?querystringkey=value");
```

Actual controller/action method code

```
    public JavaScriptResult GetContent(string querystringkey)
    {
        string url = "/FAQPage.html?key=" + querystringkey;

        return JavaScript("window.location.href = '" + url + "'");
    }
```

This works fine and does the redirection to `FAQPage.html` page but in case exception occurs while executing any action method, instead of redirecting to `FAQPage.html` page it writes the JavaScript content `window.location.href = '/FAQPage.html?key=value'` to the response stream itself.

Thus a blank screen appears with this JavaScript line. Am not able to figure out why is this happening? MSDN doc says, `JavaScriptResult` creates a JavaScript object which is written to response stream.

Please let know what is the issue here and how can I resolve this.

Comment: Your filter attribute is wrong.  You need to change it to use the MVC result APIs instead of writing the response directly.

Comment: @SLaks, thanks for the comment. Can you show an example of how to do  that?

Comment: That completely depends on how your filter works.